# Dynamically Populate Drop Down List inside Multifield in AEM

Tags: extjs, aem

I have two tabs in my dialog.First Tab is having a pathfield and second tab is having a multifield inside that only one widget of xtype selection(drop down) exist.I want to send the pathfield path as a query parameter to a servlet and want to populate json in the list.

I have done this by having a listener under drop-down widget.
i am using property render and its value:

```
function(){ 
    var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');
    var path=dialog.findById('path'); 
    $.getJSON('/bin/demo?path=' + path.value,
       function(jsonData){ 
         this.setOptions(jsonData);
         this.doLayout(false,false); 
       }
    );
}
```

My JSON response is coming but `setOptions is not a function error` is coming.
Please Help!!!!

Comment: What is the value of `this` object in function inside and outside `$.getJSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) value depends upon the context where you are making use of `this`.

I believe that is the problem here. `this` value would differ inside and outside the `$.getJSON`. You would need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method) the value of `this` object for the function.

The link has given the example also. Either you need to store reference of `this` to a variable or bind `this` reference using the bind method. [Refer this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/binding) for more details